# mac updated and now vs code will not work

Tags: visual-studio-code

The default interactive shell is now zsh.
To update your account to use zsh, please run `chsh -s /bin/zsh`.
For more details, please visit https://support.apple.com/kb/HT208050.

i dont know what to do. i looked up how to switch to zsh and run my program and that did not help. what should i do.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: my terminal is saying i need to update it to run that command but i dont want to lose the information that is in my terminal.